# MultiView and GridView Paging issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Multi View with two views in it. View1 has a Grid View and the grid-view allow paging by ten records.

The problem is i have to press page number tow times to go to that page.

The first click nothing happen the second click the grid view goes to the page what is the issue

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridusers" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="10" CssClass="table table-bordered text-nowrap" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridusers_SelectedIndexChanged"  OnRowDeleting="gridusers_RowDeleting"> 

                     <Columns>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" CausesValidation="False"  CommandName="Select" Text="" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></asp:LinkButton>

                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <controlstyle cssclass="btn btn-primary" />
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record ?');" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             <controlstyle cssclass="btn btn-danger" />
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Customer ID" SortExpression="Customer ID" />
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Customer Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact Person" HeaderText="Contact Person" SortExpression="Contact Person" />
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="P.O.Box" HeaderText="P.O.Box" SortExpression="P.O.Box" />
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HtmlEncodeFormatString="false" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Mobile No" HeaderText="Mobile No" SortExpression="Mobile No" />

                     </Columns>

               <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1"  ForeColor="#333333" />
               </asp:GridView> 

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerClass c = new CustomerClass();

        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            gridusers.DataSource = c.getcst();
            gridusers.DataBind();
        }
    }



protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gridusers.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        this.c.getcst();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not rebinding the grid once the page number changes.

Your code is this:

```
protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gridusers.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    this.c.getcst();
}
```

You need to do this instead:

```
protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gridusers.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gridusers.DataSource = c.getcst();
    gridusers.DataBind();
}
```